# How to handle certificate pop up which appears in middle of loading page using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, popup, webdriver, certificate

```
Question.
Pop up displayed in middle of  loading page
```

1]Any line of code before and after get url  wont work because pop up comes in middle of loading page

2]Certificate is about authentication for the site.we just need to click ok on that pop up

3]Robot class and alert accept wont work because pop up comes in middle of loading page.

4]Setting are disable so setting capability wont work.

is there  any other way to handle thispop up .

Comment: Show code how are you trying to do, and is possible, screenshot of pop up?

Comment: i cant share you screen shot due client data protection .
 I don't know how to handle 
code - driver.get("link");

until unless we handle the pop up it cursor does not move to next line